# Control similar to Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to bind a generic object with properties to a DataGrid, the DataGrid control allow only the binding of a List.

So I've two questions:

1. Is possible bind an object that's not a list?
2. There are similar control like Datagrid that allow to do this with the same structure?

Comment: You mean you want to show a single row with the object's properties?

Comment: @Clemens, yes 'cause I need the style structure of DataGrid but I've just one element, I think it's useless create a List for just one element, nope?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt much to call `dataGrid.ItemsSource = new object[] { yourObject }`, or `dataGrid.Items.Add(yourObject)`.

Comment: @Clemens, but you have created the object in the xaml?  I need to bind it

Comment: You could use a simple Binding Converter that returns an array with one element from the source property.

Comment: Are you saying you want something like the winforms [PropertyGrid control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid(v=vs.110).aspx)? Or do you just want your object to be a single row in the grid?

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible bind an object that's not a list?

You can bind to any `IEnumerable`. If you want to be able to edit the items, you should bind to an `IList`.

Binding to a single object is simply a matter of binding to a sequence or a collection that returns a single item, e.g.:

```
public IEnumerable SourceProperty { get { return new List<YourType>(1) { yourObject } } };
```